# Unable to send JSON response from Zend Framework 3 to Ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, zend-framework, frameworks

I am facing the following error:
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data. From Zend Framework 3 controller I am using JsonModel() to wrap the response that I want to send as a json message to the client. Please note that it does execute the ajax success function when I change the dataType to "html". But in this case either I am not able to access the data items.

Client - Ajax call , which is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){

    $("#preview").click( function(event){ 

        event.preventDefault();
        var controllerId = $(this).attr("controller-id");
        alert("coontrollerId - "+controllerId);

        $.ajax({

            url:        '/dpo/policyPreview/'+controllerId, 
            type:       'POST',
            dataType:   'json',
            data:       controllerId,
            async:      true,

            success: function(response) { 
                try {

                    alert("Result".response."status");

                } catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, thrown) {
                alert("Error");
                console.log(status);
            }

        });


    });
```

Server Side - Zend framework 3:

```
    public function previewAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest(); 
        //get parameters $query->get('showJson') == 1
        $controllerId = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('controllerId',-1);
        $query = $request->getQuery();  
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $showJson ) { 

        $view = new JsonModel([
            'status' => 'SUCCESS',
            'message'=>'Here is your data',
            'data' => [
                'full_name' => 'John Doe',
                'address' => '51 Middle st.'
            ]
        ]);

        //do not render the view
        //$view->setTerminal(true); 
        return $view;

       } else { 
          $view = new ViewModel(); 
       }  
       return $view;

    }
```

Comment: `alert("Result".response."status");` looks like you are trying to do PHP concatenation in javascript.  Javascript uses `+` for concatenation, not `.`

Comment: that is a foolish mistake but still when response is sent by server it don't enter success function at all. I realized it should be alert("Result"+response."status");

Comment: Check result of AJAX call in your browser's developer tools, "Network" tab.

Comment: This is what I get under developer tools: 
<!-- 
 * database Configuration Override
 *
 * You can use this file for overriding configuration values from modules, etc.
 * You would place values in here that are agnostic to the environment and not
 * sensitive to security.
 *
 * @NOTE: In practice, this file will typically be INCLUDED in your source
 * control, so do not include passwords or other sensitive information in this
 * file.
 *
 -->
{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Here is your data","data":{"full_name":"John Doe","address":"51 Middle st."}}